# Fade out a div with a CSS/JS gradient

Tags: javascript, css, gradient

I don't meant any fade in/out animation. I'd like to know if there is any crazy futuristic CSS property, technics or JS plugin to achieve this effect:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if the text is not faded then it's easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the entire content, I think the best option would be to use the `mask-image` property with a CSS transition:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set an object with the property:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,1),rgba(255,255,255,0))
```

Fourth argument in `rgba` is the opacity, which will help creating that fading effect while using `linear-gradient`.

Comment: This is only the background color, not the content.